# When I bolded multiple sentences within a block quote and then edited more, they disappear in preview but are visible in editor

Tags: bug, markdown, editor, markdown-rendering

I posted an answer on Stack Overflow and it's one of my first few answers. I entered almost the entire paragraph from [this page](https://opendsa-server.cs.vt.edu/ODSA/Books/CS3/html/BinaryTree.html#definitions-and-properties) that starts with "If n_1" and ended at "and its depth is 0." as well as an image and then another paragraph below.

When I tried to bold a few sentences within the quote and posted, many sentences were lost. My post is here: [What is the difference between tree depth and height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603692/what-is-the-difference-between-tree-depth-and-height/43386180#43386180)

> [image: This is what I'm seeing when I edit and it looks right in the editor but not the preview.]

I'm using Mac OS X El Capitan and Google Chrome.

I'm aware the subscripts mean italics but kinda determined that it wasn't my issue. First I tried deleting the post pictured and making a new post without the subscripts, but the same thing was happening, so I never saved that edited post, and just undeleted the post pictured.

Comment: Note, if you want that image to show up it should be `![Figure 7.2.1][1]`

Comment: You can also do subscripts with <sub> tags and superscripts with <sup> tags (but not in comments). I've edited for you :)

Answer (score 4):

I think it assumed the part beginning with `<k` to be part of an HTML tag, and removed it. I have edited the post, replacing `<` with the HTML entity `&lt;`, which should be left alone by the parser.